# Using "filters" parameter in Google API request always results in an error?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I'm experimenting with querying the Google Analaytics Core Reporting API. But I've hit a bug that I can't figure out. I'm in the early days so I've copied an example JavaScript implemtation from [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js). **Ran this, it works, lovely.**

So I started playing about with the parameters and everything seemed fine until I entered a filter, so

### This Worked

```
// Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
  // the past seven days.
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'dimensions':'ga:browser',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
  })
```

### Doesn't work

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'filters':'ga:city%3D%3DIrvine',
    'dimensions':'ga:browser',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
  })
```

Results in the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalidParameter",
            "message": "Invalidvalue'ga: city%3D%3DIrvine'forfiltersparameter."
        }],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalidvalue'ga: city%3D%3DIrvine'forfiltersparameter."
    }
}
```

I've read an re-read [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) and I can't see an issue with my filter.

So what am I missing here? Why does entering the filter, as I'm doing fail?

---

### Full code

I don't think you'll be able to run this without the ClientID, etc. but here goes (for completeness)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics - A quickstart guide for JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="auth-button" hidden>Authorize</button>

<h1>Hello Analytics</h1>

<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

<script>

  // Replace with your client ID from the developer console.
  var CLIENT_ID = 'MyClientID';

  // Set authorized scope.
  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];


  function authorize(event) {
    // Handles the authorization flow.
    // `immediate` should be false when invoked from the button click.
    var useImmdiate = event ? false : true;
    var authData = {
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      immediate: useImmdiate
    };

    gapi.auth.authorize(authData, function(response) {
      var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
      if (response.error) {
        authButton.hidden = false;
      }
      else {
        authButton.hidden = true;
        queryAccounts();
      }
    });
  }


function queryAccounts() {
  // Load the Google Analytics client library.
  gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {

    // Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then(handleAccounts);
  });
}


function handleAccounts(response) {
  // Handles the response from the accounts list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first Google Analytics account.
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for properties.
    queryProperties(firstAccountId);
  } else {
    console.log('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProperties(accountId) {
  // Get a list of all the properties for the account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list(
      {'accountId': accountId})
    .then(handleProperties)
    .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProperties(response) {
  // Handles the response from the webproperties list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {

    // Get the first Google Analytics account
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].accountId;

    // Get the first property ID
    var firstPropertyId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for Views (Profiles).
    queryProfiles(firstAccountId, firstPropertyId);
  } else {
    console.log('No properties found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProfiles(accountId, propertyId) {
  // Get a list of all Views (Profiles) for the first property
  // of the first Account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
      'accountId': accountId,
      'webPropertyId': propertyId
  })
  .then(handleProfiles)
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProfiles(response) {
  // Handles the response from the profiles list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first View (Profile) ID.
    var firstProfileId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query the Core Reporting API.
    queryCoreReportingApi(firstProfileId);
  } else {
    console.log('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
  // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
  // the past seven days.
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'filters':'ga:city%3D%3DIrvine',
    'dimensions':'ga:browser',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  })
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}

  // Add an event listener to the 'auth-button'.
  document.getElementById('auth-button').addEventListener('click', authorize);
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you try to replace `%3D%3D` with `==` , the api may already do the encoding job for you

Comment: @Hacketo... That worked o_O But it said to URL encode it??!

Comment: The examples are for HTTP requests, not using the library ^^

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters states URL Encoding: `The Google API client libraries automatically encode the filter operators.` Damn it... Cheers, feel free to add an answer @Hacketo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters), the filters encoding examples are about final HTTP requests

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
?ids=ga:12134
&dimensions=ga:browser
&metrics=ga:pageviews
&filters=ga:browser%3D~%5EFirefox
&start-date=2007-01-01
&end-date=2007-12-31
```

But the Api is already doing the encoding.

So replacing `%3D%3D` with `==` in your filter `ga:city%3D%3DIrvine` would do the job.